# How can I get latest play store version for an app

Tags: android, mobile-development

I am working on an application where I have to show if update is available or not for an applications which are installed in your device, suppose I have telegram version 10.5 in my device and telegram latest version 11.1 is available on play store. then I have to show update for it, But I am unable to get play store version of that app, it would be really helpful, if anyone can help me with this, Thanks in advance

I have been searching about it from very long, but I have only found that due to play store website changes and no support of official api, you cannot get it, please help me if anyone have solution.

Comment: What you want is pretty complicated. Accessing Google API for retrieving app info requires a Google account and a virtual device because Google Play Services and Play Store don't let you access this information. Check Aurora Store app (open source) and their libraries how to get app data from Google. Alternatively you can use one of the commercial services that provide app info data.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a [Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api) with which you can retrieve a lot of information about your own apps, but as far as I know not about other apps.

You *could* try [scraping](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/) the [Google Play Store website](https://play.google.com/store/apps) in order to retreive the app version that way, but that may violate the terms of service and would likely break after they update their website.

Alternatively, you could also search on [other stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_app_stores) for app updates as those might have public APIs for looking up the app versions. Those might be slightly different from the Play Store version as the review time is always different on all app stores.

You can also enable [cross-store updates](https://developer.android.com/google/play/app-updates#allow-updates) for your own app if your goal is just to keep your own app as much up to date as possible.

To my knowledge the Play Store has no public API for looking up app version so these are some alternative options, best of luck.

Comment: Scraping Play Store web site only works for apps that don't have different versions for different devices. For the others you will only get "varies by device" as version.